# how do I assign an ID to each label in my for loop? for kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have been trying to add the IDs to the labels I created in my for loop so I can change them later in my code this id what i have so far I have been on this the past 2 days

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class WordLabel(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WordLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 5
        self.rows = 6
        self.spacing = 5
        self.pos_hint = {"center_x": .5}
        for i in range(0, 30):
            label = Label(
                pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5},
                text=str(i+1),
                size_hint=(dp(10), dp(10)),
                color=(0, 0, 0, 1),
            )

            self.add_widget(label)


class WORDOLE5App(App):
    pass


WORDOLE5App().run()
```

Comment: You must use `kv` language to create `ids`, not python. Just make your own list or dictionary to keep track of the `Labels`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson how?

Answer (score 0):

As someone said above, you cannot add ids in Python. You can create a dictionary like this:

```
dict1 = {}
for i in range(0, 30): 
    label = Label( pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5}, 
    text=str(i+1), size_hint=(dp(10), dp(10)),    
    color=(0, 0, 0, 1), )
    dict1["Label " + str(i+1)] = label
```

Then when you want to get a particular label you call dict1[your_label_number]. For example

```
label_ten_text = dict1["Label 10"].text
```